# How to add shadow to DataTable?

Tags: flutter

I have a two DataTables. First table include one column and located on the left of second DataTable. I need to be First table cast a shadow. I tried adding a boxshadow, but it applies to everything, not just first table.
Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your DataTable inside Card widget and give it elevation

Comment: Why this is the best answer if it doesn't help you?

Comment: I find the code on flutter site and got, how Card widget works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Card(
          child: DataTable(
            //your dataTable code 
          ),
          elevation: 3.0,
        )
```

> Hope it will help